# No action from Solr SynonymGraphFilterFactory - synonyms.text not loaded?

Tags: solr, synonym

I have a setup with Solr 8.8.0 which indexes data for solr searches from a MySQL DB. This works perfectly so far. I would like to add some synonyms, but nothing happens.

I've added the "synonyms.txt" to the conf folder. "synonyms.txt" includes the following for testing:

blablabla,test

synonym,car

The "solr-data-config.xml" contains:

```
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

When I query, "blablabla" or "synonym" I get no results. When I query "test" or "car" I get results. I am expecting "blablabla" and "test" to return the same.

It seems, no matter what changes I do, that the synonyms.txt is not read/indexed. either in the index or query. I've tried setups with only index, only query and both. It does not seem to be any difference.

After adding synonyms to the synonym-file I've restarted Solr and run new dataimport. I've tried the Analysis in Solr UI, and it only return the value. Not the synonyms.

ST blablabla
LCF blablabla
SF blablabla
SF blablabl

How may I check if the "synonyms.txt" are read? If the solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory is run at all?

[image]

Comment: Hello, I see in the print screen that you used the field with name "Navn" (in the drop down list). Is this a text_general field?

Comment: @OanaB, the field type of "Navn" is text_en. Would it make i difference if I change it to text_general?

Comment: Hello, @saXen, you have put Synonyms in the text_general field type, but you tested with a "text_en" field. Do you have Synonyms in "text_en" also? From the print screen it seems not, because a SGF (SynonymGraphFilter) should have appeared.

Comment: You are right @OanaB! How could I miss this. I've now changed my setup to consistantly use type text_general. Now the SGF (SynonymGraphFilter) appears in "Analysis" and it seems to work as expected also in search. :) Thanks.